# Python - a way to train softmax keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, word2vec, softmax

I'm using keras for a personal project very close to implementation of word2vec using keras. I got everything ready including the model but whenever I try to actually train the model on batch (in my case, couples of one hot encoded embeddings of items) even if I use _yield instead of _return it still gives an error of 
"ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor...".

I got to a point where I even try training on each couple separately (aka batch size=1)bu still can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Some more info about the model I'm trying to train:
1) No of items = 3115
2) Trainset consists of couples of items according to the *win* *size* given in the item_list

Here's some code:

```
def create_all_data(all_data, items_size, window_size, shuffle):
all_couples = []
for item_list in all_data:
    couples = create_data(item_list, window_size, shuffle)
    all_couples.extend(couples)

    if all_couples:
        X, Y = zip(*all_couples)
        X = np_utils.to_categorical(X, items_size+1)
        Y = np_utils.to_categorical(Y, items_size+1)

        yield X,Y


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = num_hidden_units, input_shape = (items_size+1,)))
model.add(Dense(units = items_size+1, activation= 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'rmsprop')

num_epochs = 20
win_size = 5

train_loss = []
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for x,y in create_all_data(trainset, items_size, win_size, True):
        loss = model.train_on_batch(x, y)
        train_loss.append(loss)
    print(epoch, loss)
```

And the error I get:

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[704,3116] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
     [[{{node loss_2/dense_6_loss/clip_by_value/Minimum}} = Minimum[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@train...ad/Reshape"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss_2/dense_6_loss/truediv, loss_2/dense_6_loss/sub)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

Comment: Can you share a bit of code?

Comment: @anand_v.singh Thanks. I edited the question with some code and the exact error I'm getting.

Comment: Try running this in Google Collab notebook, If this problem persists there just load one Image and see the graph at tensorboard and show the results, if it still fails, share the definition of trainset variable.

Comment: @anand_v.singh I tried it also on Google Colab and got the exact same warning. And another one saying that I used almost all my GPU memory limit. I can't seem to find the problem :/.. My trainset consists of pairs of items obtained from _itemlists_ of each user. Just like word2vec with sentences. My sentences are list of items of users and my words are the items themselves. Have ~4K item lists, each consisting of 10-200 items.

Answer (score 0):

You have two infinite generators and you are trying to `zip()` them and then `Yeild` them at once, that is not allowed, allowed is maybe not the right term, if you use zip you try to yield all the data at once, which almost guarantees you running out of memory, Check out this link for more https://pybit.es/generators.html

You would rather need to use the yield function for that.

A crude implementation of that is

```
def zipper(Xgen, Ygen):
    while True:
        yield (Xgen.next(), Ygen.next())
```

This will yield X and Y one by one rather than all at once which should keep the memory used in check.

**Edit** 
Theoretically the code below should work, if it doesn't I will create a chat room and we will figure it out.

```
def create_all_data(all_data, items_size, window_size, shuffle):
all_couples = []
for item_list in all_data:
    couples = create_data(item_list, window_size, shuffle)
    all_couples.extend(couples)

    if all_couples:
        X, Y = zip(*all_couples)
        X = np_utils.to_categorical(X, items_size+1)
        Y = np_utils.to_categorical(Y, items_size+1)

        yield (X.next(),Y.next())
```

The reason there is a maybe is because for the above code I assume that all_data is creating the infinite stream, and have thus tried to feed it's split into the graph via a generator one at a time.

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help but I'd be happy with some more information how to actually use the _zipper_ function in the code. Do I call it **instead** of the _zip_ function? or before or after to actually be able to generate each time just one pair to feed into the model?

Comment: Apparently, _.next_ does not work with numpy arrays so it didn't really help. At the end I decided to change the loss from _categorical_ _cross_ _entropy_ to _sparse_ _categorical_ _cross_ _entropy_, seems to be working better now. By the way, turns out I still can't use the chat of the website because of my reputation :/